# How to load external XML to get data into Phonegap app

Tags: javascript, xml, cordova

I am building an app using Phonegap that grabs data from an external URL, then displays the info using javascript.

I have

here is my code in my index file to grab the xml:

```js
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {/* code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari */ xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); }
else {/* code for IE6, IE5 */ xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://EXAMPLESITE.com/EXAMPLE.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

I am currently testing this using xcode and cannot get it to display anything on the emulator or on a test device.

I have also tried adding an ExternalHosts key in the plist and listed the domain I am trying to access.

Can someone please me troubleshoot this?  Thank you

Comment: On Apple devices, I was able to get it to pull from one server but not another, so it does appear to be a security issue.

I have now tried this on Android and it does not pull any data from a remote XML file.  If I have the file local it displays no problem. My config.xml has <access origin="*"/>.  I was using Phonegap 2.1.0, so I upgraded that to 2.9.0. My manifest file has <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />.  I cannot find anything else to even try so I am not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

XMLHttpRequest is asynchronous, you need to wait for the XML to load before trying to access it. For this, you can use the `onLoad` handler:

```js
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {/* code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari */ xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); }
else {/* code for IE6, IE5 */ xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://EXAMPLESITE.com/EXAMPLE.xml",false);
xmlhttp.onLoad = function() {
    // Data is loaded, now it can be used:
    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
    // Do something with xmlDoc...
}
xmlhttp.send();
```

There are other things you should look for like errors, etc. see the full documentation there - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: That makes sense, but it still does not appear to be pulling any data.  When I just download the XML file, it works fine since it is local, but I just cannot get it to pull from the external site.  I am not getting any errors, but I am not sure the best way to test where it is failing.

Comment: I'm not familiar how to debug cordova applications, but did you try checking that the code is working using `console.info` statements? If the code is working locally but not remotely, it could also be some security or sandbox issue.

Comment: It appears it is an issue on the server.  I tried getting the xml from a different server and it pulled the data no problem.  SO I am thinking it is an issue on the server with the xml where it is not allowing access to the xml from external sites